# Update database with data from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, database

I am using

```
$.getJSON(uri).done(function(data){...}
```

To get an array of data from a table in my database.

Within the js function, I am letting the user delete items from the array "data".

How can I make these changes show up on the database?

I have a c# function that will delete a record given an Id as a parameter.

Comment: If you want user changes to be immediately reflected in the database, just do Ajax requests every time, to notify the server of these changes. Send some data, like `{"action" : "delete", "id" : 35}`, and use these in the backend to perform these actions.

Comment: As @blex said, you need to have some backend code handling that "delete" request, that is the right, beautiful and organized way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If You use asp.net mvc You can use method in Your controller or in api controller.

Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
     //Your code
     if(result==true){
          return Content("true");
     }else{
          return Content("false");
     }

}
```

And jquery:

```
 _jq.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/id=?someID',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if(data=='true'){
                     alert('ok');
                }else{
                     alert('false');
                }
            },
            error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error')
            }
 });
```